# Change the plot order in scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I am trying to plot a bunch of dots on a map: these are my Latitudes (AX,BX,CX,...) and Longitudes (AY,BY,CY,...) and my code:

```
Xpos=[AX, BX, CX, DX, EX,SouXposJun,LonXposJun,ImmXposJun,LeiXposJun,FelXposJun,ZeelXposJun,RotXposJun,AmsXposJun])
Ypos=[AY, BY, CY, DY, EY,SouYposJun,LonYposJun,ImmYposJun,LeiYposJun,FelYposJun,ZeelYposJun,RotYposJun,AmsYposJun])

#%% map

ax=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
#colors

color=[]
color[0:7500]=np.tile('red',7500)#A
color[7500:92400]=np.tile('orange',84900)#B
color[92400:288600]=np.tile('green',196200)#C
color[288600:752400]=np.tile('darkred',463800)#D
color[752400:775920]=np.tile('gold',23520)#E
color[775920:800000]=np.tile('darkgrey',24080)#Ports


plt.subplot(231)#Start of release

m= Basemap(width=1000000,height=1000500,projection='lcc',
        resolution='h',lat_0=52.25,lon_0=1)
m.drawmapscale(lon=6.5, lat=48.5, lon0=0, lat0=48.5, length=50) 
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='turquoise')
m.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='aqua')
m.drawcountries(linestyle='--')
plt.title("17/02/2013",size=15)
x,y = m(XposFeb[33],YposFeb[33])
scatter = m.scatter([], [], s=0.1, c=color, marker='o', label = 'Aurelia aurita', zorder=2)
scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[x,y])
```

The problem is this first plots the dots A,B,C.. and over these the rest. Since they overlap, I can no longer see A, B, C, ... **Is there a way to plot the first values of Xpos and Ypos over the last values?** So I can see A, B, C better than the rest? Preferably without me having to completely reorganise my code.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's `ma`?...

Comment: @Lupacante. It's a function to combine masked arrays

Comment: You might want to add `from numpy import ma` to the top of your code then. Also, what's A? If you could write a  minimal working example, that'd be great

Comment: This will probably help you: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html